# can create a google map by lat, long in jquery . google maps api

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

i have `lat, long` values of a place . how can i create a google map for that `lat , long` using `googl maps api , jquery`

is this possible ??

currently iv am getting the lat , long values using

```
        var address = jQuery('#business-address').val();
        var city = jQuery('.city').val();
        var state = jQuery('.state').val();
        var country = jQuery('.country').val();

        var address_string = address+","+city+","+state+","+country;

        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

           if (geocoder) {
              geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address_string }, function (results, status) {
                 if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    alert(results[0].geometry.location);
                 }
                 else {
                    alert("Geocoding failed: " + status);
                 }
              });
           }
```

Comment: Take a look at the first and most simple example from the API docs [here](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple). View source and there you have it.